# Is it unnecessary to put an "a" in this sentence "It’s very challenging work"?

Tags: meaning, word-usage

To describe my job, I could say

> it’s very challenging work

Is unnecessary to put an "a" in this sentence

> It’s **a** very challenging work

In a different context, my boss gives my a very difficult task, I need to finish it in a very short time. Should I say

> It’s very challenging work

or

> It’s **a** very challenging work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Work," in this sense, is an uncountable or [mass noun](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mass_noun), so including the article "a" in your examples is ungrammatical. "It's very challenging work" is correct in both situations.

All good dictionaries should indicate when a noun is uncountable. For example, [Cambridge English Dictionary shows](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/work):

> A1 [ U ]
>   an activity, such as a job, that a person uses physical or mental effort to do, usually for money

The [ U ] [indicates](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/help/codes.html) the noun is uncountable.

---

That said, "work" also has other meanings, some of which are countable!

> B2 [ C ] something created as a result of effort, especially a painting, book, or piece of music

So a musician, speaking to a friend about the difficulty of a piece of music, could say "It's **a** very challenging work." This *is* grammatical because it's referring to a specific creation rather than work in general.